# Localhost port 8000 and 8888 redirect to 8080

Tags: localhost, ports

I can't track down what's forcing localhost:8000 and localhost:8888 to redirect to localhost:8080. Is there anyone out there that has an idea? I'm on a local machine, mac os x, not a server. I've used jekyll, pow, haproxy, nodejs, webrick, and mamp. Right now none of them are running (as far as I know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bash script that will kill the process running on a specific port.

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:3000 | grep LISTEN | tr -s ' ' | cut -f 2 -d ' ' | xargs kill -9
```

Just replace `3000` with the desired port you'd like to kill.

This should clear all your ports for you:

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:8080 | grep LISTEN | tr -s ' ' | cut -f 2 -d ' ' | xargs kill -9
lsof -n -i4TCP:8888 | grep LISTEN | tr -s ' ' | cut -f 2 -d ' ' | xargs kill -9
lsof -n -i4TCP:8000 | grep LISTEN | tr -s ' ' | cut -f 2 -d ' ' | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of tiny tools that can do that for you. Search for port forwarding tools...

You can also make a tunnel with ssh.

Comment: I think I might have worded the title wrong. The ports are forwarding and I dont know how / why. How can I go about stopping the forwarding?